# trying to understand the transition method in javascript d3js framework?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to use Donut3D.js provided from d3js.org. However, i am confused on the below line

> Donut3D.transition("salesDonut", randomData(), 130, 100, 30, 0.4);

What does thoes end number stand for ?

> 130, 100, 30, 0.4

I don't see any documentation for that ? can someone help me understand those numbers that are being passed.

```
var salesData=[
    {label:"Used", color:"#FF3300"},
    {label:"Free", color:"#00FF00"}
];

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",700).attr("height",300);

svg.append("g").attr("id","salesDonut");


Donut3D.draw("salesDonut", randomData(), 150, 150, 130, 100, 30, 0.4);

function changeData(){
     Donut3D.transition("salesDonut", randomData(), 130, 100, 30, 0.4);
}

function randomData(){
    return salesData.map(function(d){ 
        return {label:d.label, value:1000*Math.random(), color:d.color};});
}
</script>
```

http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/9994181

Comment: If you need it, this is a solid explanation of .transition() http://alignedleft.com/projects/2014/easy-as-pi/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Donut3D definition is right there in the page and its draw method as well

```
Donut3D.draw=function(id, data, x /*center x*/, y/*center y*/, 
        rx/*radius x*/, ry/*radius y*/, h/*height*/, ir/*inner radius*/)
```

there you can see what each value stands for

Answer (score 2):

From https://gist.github.com/NPashaP/9994181

```
         Donut3D.draw=function(id, data, x /*center x*/, y/*center y*/, 
        rx/*radius x*/, ry/*radius y*/, h/*height*/, ir/*inner radius*/)
```